# What is the correct way to effect multiple updates on a Neo4J graph?

Tags: java, scala, neo4j, cypher

I am cutting my teeth on Neo4J. I am trying to understand what is the correct way of effecting multiple, simultaneous changes on a Graph DB.

Before I begin, let me clarify that because of a couple of reasons, I have to use Neo4J as an embedded database, in a Java/Scala application and not as a remote server to which I can throw REST calls. Moreover, I have to use Cypher to construct the commands and execute using Neo4J's Java API: `exectureQuery`

So, here's a piece of code to exemplify what I am trying to do:

```
val db = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase()
val query1 =
  """
    |Create (d: Dish {name:"Fish Curry",from:"India"}),
    |(t: Table {no: 1}),
    |(d)-[r:ORDERED_FROM]->(t)
  """.stripMargin
val query2 =
    """
    |Match (d:Dish {name: "Fish Curry"}), 
    |(t: Table {no: 1}), 
    |(d)-[r:ORDERED_FROM]->(t)
    |Delete r
    """.stripMargin

val query3 =
  """
   |Match (d:Dish {name: "Fish Curry"}), (t: Table {no: 1})
   |Create (d)-[r:SERVED_AT]->(t)
  """.stripMargin
```

Let's say I am modelling a typical evening in a restaurant. I choose a particular dish from the menu and place an order for it. At this point, *query1* is fired. The nodes and relationships are created.

```
val v1 = db.execute(query1).resultAsString()
// ... I consume 'v1' appropriately
```

After some time, the dish is ready and is served. Now, for the graph to to reflect what has happened, following commands are fired:

```
val v2 = db.execute(query2).resultAsString
val v3 = db.execute(query3).resultAsString
```

To elaborate (it is perhaps obvious to all the Neo4J experts here anyway), I am severing the relationship of *ORDERED_FROM* between dish and table, and tying them through a relationship of *SERVED_AT*.

I have two questions:

1. Because I am making 2 updates through two separate Cypher queries, I am perhaps missing on the transactional guarantee. Between removal of old Relationship and addition of the new one, the *dish* is vulnerable to another orthogonal update (perhaps by another thread of execution). If this understanding is correct, then what I must do to prevent it?
2. In the example above, the properties of *Dish* node is hardcoded. But, in practice, these are going to be  variables, their values being assigned at runtime. Therefore, it is possible that either *Dish* or *Table* may not be found while query{2,3} are executed. What is the correct way to deal with that? There may not be any exception thrown, if I understand the API correctly.

I have searched through various blogs and other sites to find an answer but I haven't. So, if the answer I am seeking already exists somewhere, please point that out to me.

Any help, is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a transaction outside of your query execution. Otherwise Cypher will start an implicit tx just for the one query.

```
try (Transaction tx= db.beginTx()) {
   db.execute(query1,params).close();
   db.execute(query1,params).close();
   tx.success();
}
```

note, this uses try-with-resource, otherwise you have to call `tx.close()` manually.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could you also give a little hint to answer my 2nd question? In the code block you have shared, if I want to execute the 2nd query only if 1st query has confirmed a _match_ (and return of a column value),  then what should I do? Is it even possible, allowed or advised? TIA.